# Failed upload to TestFlight due to Invalid Binary - iOS app using Firebase Messaging for Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, testflight, app-bundle

I am using firebase messaging for notifications in my iOS app and when I uploaded a build to TestFlight, it gave me a few problems:

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/[AppName].app/UserNotifications.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/[AppName].app/UserNotifications.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/[AppName].app/UserNotifications.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

What is that supposed to mean?

I did not find anything related to that problem. I have seen that in my Framework list there is UserNotification.framework and it is marked as Do not Embed. I was afraid to change that and bug the whole thing and I believe this is a native Xcode configuration. Anything in mind?